# xRDP session ends after succesful login for root

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, vnc

I installed xRDP and tigervnc server on a CentOS 7 VM. All users can login succesfully but "root". When I try login to VM with root, the connection establishes but after 4-5 seconds the RDP session ends with nothing. Other users never create a problem while logging. I created a new user and even it logged in without any problem. Just root cannot login, actually logs in but session closes immediately after login.

I'm sharing contents of xrdp.log and xrdp-sesman.log files at below.

---

xrdp-sesman.log:

```
[20190618-10:45:49] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 57136
[20190618-10:45:49] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username root, ip 10.45.9.107:55728 - socket: 12
[20190618-10:45:49] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20190618-10:45:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5912)
[20190618-10:45:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6012)
[20190618-10:45:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6212)
[20190618-10:45:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190618-10:45:49] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 68286
[20190618-10:45:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190618-10:45:49] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20190618-10:45:49] [INFO ] Xvnc :12 -auth .Xauthority -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 16 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/sesman_passwd-root@blmdvsparkt1.internal.borusan.com:12 -bs -nolisten tcp -localhost -dpi 96
[20190618-10:45:49] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 68292) to exit
[20190618-10:45:55] [CORE ] window manager (pid 68292) did exit, cleaning up session
[20190618-10:45:55] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 68286
[20190618-10:45:55] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20190618-10:45:55] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_12
[20190618-10:45:55] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_12
[20190618-10:45:55] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /tmp/.xrdp/xrdpapi_12
[20190618-10:45:55] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username root, display :12.0, session_pid 68286, ip 10.45.9.107:55728 - socket: 12
```

---

xrdp.log:

```
[20190618-10:48:03] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20190618-10:48:03] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20190618-10:48:03] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20190618-10:48:03] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20190618-10:48:03] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 12
[20190618-10:48:03] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC started connecting
[20190618-10:48:03] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC connecting to 127.0.0.1 5912
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC tcp connected
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC security level is 2 (1 = none, 2 = standard)
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC password ok
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending share flag
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving server init
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving pixel format
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving name length
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving name
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending pixel format
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending encodings
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending framebuffer update request
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending cursor
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC connection complete, connected ok
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:57150)
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] VNC got clip data
[20190618-10:48:04] [DEBUG] VNC got clip data
[20190618-10:48:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 10.10.31.95:3389)
[20190618-10:48:09] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20190618-10:48:09] [DEBUG] VNC mod_exit
[20190618-10:48:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:32926)
[20190618-10:48:09] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
```

Comment: `window manager (pid 68292) did exit`, you should investigate why. Maybe it refuses to work with root privileges? In general logging in as root this way seems like a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Actually we don't allow root login on other machines but this situtation is special. Thanks for your help, I will check why.